# Performance: Get and group productdetails from 5 tables in a single query instead of multiples?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-performance, query-performance

Currently I'm developing a background cms for an online shop.

I split the tables as follow in my database:
-products
-productdetails (descrition...)
-productimages
-product variants (colors..)
-product cross selling

Now on the product edit page i need to fetch all data for a single product.
So my question is how i can get those details more efficient then make 3-5 database calls.

Or would the processing with php be less efficient then make those 3-5 calls ?

At the moment the query looks like that:

```
SELECT 
        pr.id, pr.categorieid, pr.itemnumber, pr.barcode, pr.price, pr.weight, pr.gender, pr.manufracture, pr.fsk18, pr.condition, pc.id AS pcid, pc.productcrossid, pc.sort, pd.productname, 
        pd.productdesc, pd.additional, pd.linktitle, pd.metatitle, pd.metadesc, pd.urlkeywords, pi.id AS piid, pi.wichimage, pi.variantid, pi.image, pi.imagealt, pv.id AS pvid, pv.variant,
        pv.variantvalue, pv.sku, pv.price AS pvprice, pv.weight AS pvweight, pv.stock, pv.special
    FROM 
        products pr
    LEFT JOIN 
        productcross as pc
        ON pr.id = pc.productid 
    LEFT JOIN 
        productdetails as pd
        ON pr.id = pd.productid     
    LEFT JOIN 
        productimage as pi
        ON pr.id = pi.productid AND pd.lang = pi.lang
    LEFT JOIN 
        productvariants as pv
        ON pr.id = pv.productid
    WHERE 
        pr.id = :id
    ORDER BY pd.lang ASC
```

As result i recieve many rows, because of the left join each value get joined with the rows i joined before.

The problem is there are dynamic many rows for cross selling, variants, images, so it can be random if variants or images are more (else i could group them atleast because each variant can get an own image, but there can be also more images then variants)

Products 1 row, productdetails according to how many languages are used, most likely 3.

Edit: According to Explain and the indexes i set, the performance of this single query is very good.

**Edit**:

According Paul Spiegel i tryed using GROUP_CONCAT

```
   SELECT 
        pr.id, pr.categorieid, pr.itemnumber, pr.barcode, pr.price, pr.weight, pr.gender, pr.manufracture, pr.fsk18, pr.condition, pc.id AS pcid, pc.productcrossid, pc.sort, pd.productname, 
        pd.productdesc, pd.additional, pd.linktitle, pd.metatitle, pd.metadesc, pd.urlkeywords
    FROM 
        products pr
    LEFT JOIN 
        productsdetails as pd
        ON pr.id = pd.productid     
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(productcrossid) AS pcproductcrossid, GROUP_CONCAT(sort) AS pcsort, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS pcid, productid
        FROM productscross
        WHERE productid = :id
        ) pc 
        ON pr.id = pc.productid 

    WHERE 
        pr.id = :id
    ORDER BY pd.lang ASC
```

Comment: The problem is: You can't get what you want in a single query, since a single query will return a single table as result. You can get one-to-one relations (like details) with the main query. But one-to-many relations (like variants) should be fetched in a separate query and linked to the corresponding products in PHP. You might though try to use subqueries with GROUP_CONCAT() or JSON_ARRAYAGG() and parse the result in PHP.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel   thats may a very good idea to use group_concat(). Gonna try it now, thanks.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel    thats working insanely good, will the concat grouping and the processing after be more efficient ? May you can write everything as an answer so i could accept it as solution =).

Comment: The query is about 2,5 times slower with group_concat and 4 sub querys, dont have enough data to test the same with many rows.

Comment: Just run multiple queries. At least when the DB is on localhost. I wouldn't like to use GROUP_CONCAT() in my production code. You never know when you are about to run into [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) limit. Adjusting it is again one more query. Then you need to parse the result in PHP. What you win on query time, you might lose in PHP processing the result.

Comment: To my way of thinking, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution - least wise when you have a presentation layer available.

Comment: @Strawberry     How you would handle this data fetch then ? Fetching all of them at own witouth using group_concat ? A simple query withouth using Join or something else would take about 0,003 seconds, and the big one with left joins and group_concat about 0,013-0,025. But i still got less data in it, no clue how this values change if there is more data, but i dont expect many difference because of the indexes.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel     i wont reach the limit, the columns with big data is left joined witouth group_cocnat, the other columns at maximum reach 250 character i guess.

Comment: I would say that your original query is the correct approach. If that query returns unwanted rows, then we can look at modifying that query to suit. Obviously, that would require a proper MCVE.

Comment: @Strawberry     not unwanted directly, but the rows multiply foreach left join. As example if i have as result 3 rows on first 2 tables and join variants (wich i cant group into those 3 rows), i get for 5 variants 15 rows. Then the next left joins for cross sales do the same and at the end i can recieve 10-50 rows (depends on how many rows there are for variants, cross sales ...). Its hard to process them correctly, but im not sure if its the correct way to go for even im able to proccess them with some loops.

Comment: Yeah, I'd still do that kind of processing in the application code.

Answer (score 1):

> As result i recieve many rows, because of the left join each value get joined with the rows i joined before.

That's not what `LEFT` means.

`X JOIN Y ON ...` delivers rows that show up on *both* `X` and `Y`.
`X LEFT JOIN Y ON ...` delivers all the rows of `X` even if there is no matching row (or rows) in `Y`.

You might get "many rows" because the relationship is "1:many".  Think of `Classes JOIN Students`  With `JOIN` you get multiple rows per `Class` (one per student), *except* for any classes without any students.  With `LEFT JOIN`, you additionally get a row for any Class with no students.

Your query with products will be a huge explosion of rows.  All products, expanded by multiple details by multiple images, etc.  It will be a mess.

In the `EXPLAIN`, *multiply* the numbers in the "Rows" column -- that will be a *crude* metric of how big the result set will be.

Use one query to get the images; another to get the colors; etc.  Use `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN` only when needed.

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is handy sometimes.  It might be useful to list the "colors".  But for "images", you would then have to split it up so you can build multiple `<img..>` tags.  That's rather easy to do, but it is extra work.

It is usually 'wrong' to have 1:1 mapping between tables.  In such cases, why not have a single table?

Do not fear 3-5 queries.  We are talking milliseconds.  The rendering of the page is likely to take several times as long as the `SELECTs`.  I often have several dozen queries to build a web page, yet I am satisfied with the performance.  And, yes, I ascribe to the notion of putting all the info about one 'product' on the page at once (when practical).  It's much better than having to click here to get the colors and click there to see the images, etc.

Comment: i just fear the case if a large number of people using the site and its not optimized well. For this page i will be forced to make more then 5 database calls. It will slow down the page for 0,2 - 0,3 seconds and if there are more people at the same time it will be even more + overhead may. But i will do some research on opcache, may i can reduce overhead like that ;).

Comment: 20 pages per second should be easy.  200 may be possible.  Beyond that, we should look deeper into the queries and overall design.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hitting so many query's you can refer to the concept which is known as flat tables in magento.

The logic behind using this concept is that what ever important data which is required to be show on the front end is stored in single table itself as well as the data is stored in there prescriptive tables.

So while querying you just need to pick the data from that flat table itself rather than querying to multiple tables and increasing the query execution time.

For reference Please check out the below link,Hope this helps.

Visit http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/06/10/magento-flat-tables/

I do know the question is not regarding Magento but you can build your own logic to achieve this mechanism.